# How to convert PDF version 1.3 to version 1.7 using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation

Using PyPDF2 I have transformed the pages of a book in a PDF which seems to be of version 1.3 and I am unable to see anything in the pdf except blank white pages when I open it using Adobe Acrobat Reader. I think it's due to the old version of the PDF. I have tried various ways to get the version to 1.7 or above but nothing worked.
So is there any way to get the PDF from version 1.3 to 1.7 using Python or any other ways.
Edit: As I was asked for the code, here it is

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, Transformation,PdfReader,PdfWriter

reader_base = PdfReader("new_pdf.pdf")
page_box_lst = reader_base.pages
reader_base_1 = PdfReader("merged_pdf.pdf")
page_base_lst = reader_base_1.pages
height = float(page_base_lst[0].mediabox.top)
new_pages = []
val = 0
writer = PdfWriter()
number_lst = []
angle = 90
for i in range(1,200):
    print(i)
    if i in number_lst:
        continue
    page_box = page_box_lst[i]
    number_lst.append(i)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        page_box_1 = page_box_lst[i + 1]
        angle = 90
        number_lst.append(i + 1)
    else:
        angle = 270
        page_box_1 = page_box_lst[i + 3]
        number_lst.append(i + 3)
    page_base = page_base_lst[i]
    height_1 = float(page_box.mediabox.right) * 0.8
    page_box.rotate(angle)
    page_box_1.rotate(angle)
    page_box.transfer_rotation_to_content()
    page_box_1.transfer_rotation_to_content()
    page_base.mergeScaledTranslatedPage(page_box, 0.8, tx=-0.015 * float(page_box.mediabox.top), ty=height - height_1)
    page_base.mergeScaledTranslatedPage(page_box_1, 0.8, tx=-0.015 * float(page_box.mediabox.top), ty=0)
    writer.add_page(page_base)

with open("result.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

The only work this code does is to arrange two pages of the input pdf file into a single page with suitable dimensions.

Comment: The PDF version number is almost certainly a red herring here. Do you have a particular reason to think that is the problem? It sounds like a problem with either PyPDF2, or with the input file.

Comment: I am sure that there is no problem with the input file but yes I suspect that Adobe doesn't read PDFs created by other generators. But why am I unable to print it as blank pages come out when I try to print it.

Comment: Adobe Reader has no problem reading PDF files from other producers, so long as they are valid. I suggest resubmitting this question with your PyPDF2 code. Are you able to supply a non-confidential input file which exhibits this error? That would be helpful.

Comment: @johnwhitington I have tested this code against other files and the too give the same error.