# Unable to print pdf created by PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I created a modified pdf using the python library PyPDF2 but when I try to print it using my printer all I get is a set of blank pages. The Adobe Reader is also not able to read the newly created PDF file which makes me think that most probably the pdf is being read by the printer but the format is inappropriate for printing. And the problem is I don't have much knowledge about PDFs and their formats.
For example a pdf that does print has a format:

[image: Viewed in notepad]

And for the pdf that I created and which doesn't print, the format is:

[image]

Hence, I would like to know what is the problem with the PDF I created using PyPDF2 and how can I fix it for printing it.
Edit:
The code used by me can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363779/how-to-convert-pdf-version-1-3-to-version-1-7-using-python) on my previous post.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you've tried?

Comment: Nothing can be concluded from looking at the PDF "source". It neither has anything to do with the PDF version. The problem probably is in the page appearance source (`/Contents`). And this is hard to debug from looking at your referred-to code - but it must be wrong at some point. Also possible of that there is some bug in pypdf2 itself.